# Почему рецепт unique_justseen() из Itertools Recipes так сложно реализован?

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы

В документации Питона в разделе [10.1.2. Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) находится такой рецепт:

> ```
> def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
>     "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
>     # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
>     # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
>     return map(next, map(operator.itemgetter(1), itertools.groupby(iterable, key)))
> ```

По моему это напрасно сложное, так как команду `return` возможно написать так:

```
     return map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(iterable, key))
```

Это прекрасно работает, но может быть, что я что-то не заметил а существует такой пример `iterable`, с которым "официальная" версия работает правильно, но моя нет.

Знаете такой случай, или мой подход кажется правильным?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант `map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby(iterable, key))` не является верным, так как вы вернете значения ключа полученное при использовании функции key. То есть при выполнении `map(operator.itemgetter(0), itertools.groupby('AabBCC', str.lower))` вы получите результат `['a', 'b', 'c']` соответствующий ключам, но не первому встреченному элементу.

Выполняя `map(next, map(operator.itemgetter(1), itertools.groupby('AabBCC', str.lower)))` получим `['A', 'b', 'C']` что соответствует первому встреченному элементу группы.